# Is there any way to acquire focus on a div popup?

Tags: javascript, vb.net

From searching the internet and StackOF, I see that my question has been asked before or at least some variation of it; but I cannot identify any real solutions.

I have acquired some code that utilizes div tags to produce a modal popup window. While this seems to work adequately aesthetically, there is a small problem of acquiring and retaining focus on the popup that would allow the user to use the tab key to navigate to screen.

```
    function PopUp() {
    $('#<%= divPopUp.ClientID%>').modal(
    {
        overlayCss: {
            backgroundColor: '#000'
        },
        onShow: function (d) { d.container.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '10px' }); }
    });
    window.location.hash = 'SubmitButton';
    }
```

The div tag refers to a table element that contains some labels and a couple of asp LinkButtons. The function is called from the Server-side using the ScriptManager component to Register and display the popup.

So far I've tried to set the focus from the Server side code and also made a few attempts based on others suggestions from the Client side but nothing gives.

Is there anyone here who has struggled with this or a very similar issue that wouldn't mind sharing a solution? Or is this expected behavior under the circumstances that can only be circumvented via alternative methods?

I've included VB.Net as a tag on this post because that's the Server code language.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS**

Inside the modal open or complete function , add this line

```
    function PopUp() {
       $('#<%= divPopUp.ClientID%>').modal(
       {
            focus:true,
            overlayCss: {
                    backgroundColor: '#000'
           },
        .....//All other stuff
        });
    }
```

OR
Use this in onshow function

```
    $('#<%= divPopUp.ClientID%>').focus();
```

Comment: Thanks Ani but that doesn't seem to work. Unless I'm placing the line of code you're suggesting in the wrong place. Could you copy the code I posted and insert your proposed solution in it?

Comment: Ok, actually that's what I thought you meant. We tried that several weeks ago but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle link and replicate the problem there ?

Comment: I'll have to strip some confidential information from the code but I'll do that and provide the link later.

Comment: I can help you more if you provide the fiddle link...Also, are you using any modal plugin ?

Comment: Hey Ani, I am accepting your answer. It turns out that if I stripped the body of the existing code I posted, created a couple of text boxes in a div and made direct calls to the div elements and then used the focus() method I was able to tab through the elements. I also didn't take into account that Labels can't be navigated via tabs (or so thats what I've found through searches anyway). I am still struggling a bit getting the Linkbuttons to get tabbed but I can work to figure out the issue there. For the most part, your answer was correct. Thanks!